# Tabulator: Difference between table.navigate and cell.navigate

Tags: tabulator

In tabulator there are two ways to navigate across table, via table and via cell, for example, table.navigateNext, table.navigatePrev, cell.navigateNext, cell navigatePrev.

Is there a difference between table.navigate... and cell.navigate...

Thank you.